# Can't build for Android with error "Failed resolution of R$color" after build JAR

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

While I run the project with an implementation **project(path: ':rocket_library')** then the resource (Ex: R.color.color_rocket_web) file works fine. But after building the JAR file and include the JAR with project resource not found. Is it possible to attach the resource files in a JAR?

The color not found from the project:
[image]

Library code: 
On runtime also not found from Libray.

```
import infix.imrankst1221.rocket.library.R

fun getThemePrimaryColor(mContext : Context): Int {
    return PreferenceUtils.getInstance().getIntegerValue(Constants.KEY_COLOR_PRIMARY, ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.my_color))
}
```

Runtime exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Linfix/imrankst1221/rocket/library/R$color;
            at infix.imrankst1221.rocket.library.utility.UtilMethods.getThemePrimaryColor(UtilMethods.kt:65)
            at infix.imrankst1221.codecanyon.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "infix.imrankst1221.rocket.library.R$color" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/infix.imrankst1221.rocket.web-_mlMdyx2A0UqLZig9zkW5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/infix.imrankst1221.rocket.web-_mlMdyx2A0UqLZig9zkW5Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

Library Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/')
    into('libs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'rocket_web.jar')
}
```

Comment: I found a temporary solution, JAR file does not content the resource files but AAR file can. So now I am using AAR file.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a comment!!
I dont have musch privilege to  comment

Did you tried these..?

1. Clean Project and Rebuild.(Build -> Clean Project and rebuild)
2. Invalidate Cache and Restart (Files -> Invalidate Caches /Restart)

Comment: Yap, I try it, even I delete all the cash file. Also, try to create a new project and import the AAR but still the same.